# can i make this into 1 switch case instead of many if else statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

```
const ticket = {
                   movie : document.getElementById("movie").value,
                   amount : document.getElementById("amount").value,
               };
```

This is my object and I want to validate input. But I'm not sure how to change if-else statements to one switch case, since it has different statements.

PS: for learning purpose I need to use javaScript and not jQuery.

```
if(ticket.movie ===""){
    document.getElementById("warningMovie").innerHTML = "need to choose a movie"
}else{
    document.getElementById("warningMovie").innerHTML = "";
}

if(ticket.amount === ""){
    document.getElementById("warningAmount").innerHTML = "need to choose amount"
}else{
     document.getElementById("warningAmount").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

I am using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and
a [Conditional operator (ternary)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) twice :)

and add the key of the object to the ID of the span - I could use warningAmount but then I would have to capitalise the key

Note the object could have been created by looping over input elements

Also ignore `("aeiou".indexOf(item[0].toLowerCase())>=0?"n ":" ")` if you do not like it

```js
const ticket = {
  movie: "",
  amount: 0,
  snack: "Chips",
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(ticket)) {
  document.getElementById("warning_" + key).innerHTML = 
    value ? "" : 
    "need to choose a"+ ("aeiou".indexOf(key[0].toLowerCase())>=0?"n ":" ") + key
}
```

```html
<span id="warning_movie"></span><br/>
<span id="warning_amount"></span><br/>
<span id="warning_snack"></span><br/>
```

Comment: shouldn't `item` be declared in some way? im a bit confused with this syntax. What `item` stands for?

Answer (score 0):

I would use ternary operator in this case. Eg.:

```
document.getElementById("warningMovie")
 .innerHTML = ticket.movie ? "" : "need to choose a movie"
```

Comment: in this case i still have to write line for each warning i want to display right?
Is there a way to minimize repetition in this case? in my original code i have 6 if else statements which looks very repetitive and i was hoping it is posible to minimize repetition in this case

Comment: For that you may use for like mplungjan has given.